# Which info is visible to the customer when creating a subscription?

Tags: android-pay

When creating a subscription the customer can see the "name" of the subscription.
Is there a way to display additional information for each subscription in the subscription panel of the customers wallet? 
Right now if the subscribe to multiple services they can not distinguish the subscription by name only.

Comment: +1 Agreed - that would be nice :) Though to answer your question, AFAIK, the `description` isn't displayed to the user in their Wallet UI - its only displayed in the purchase process...